# Android :crash on webRtc on VideoCapturerThread

Tags: android, webrtc

I have implemented video call using `webrtc` in android but I have this crush .It is not produced all times but only when there are multiple user session in the app.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: VideoCapturerThread
                                                 Process: fapp.id, PID: 4870
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Not on camera thread.
                                                     at org.webrtc.CameraCapturer.checkIsOnCameraThread(CameraCapturer.java:559)
                                                     at org.webrtc.CameraCapturer.access$000(CameraCapturer.java:20)
                                                     at org.webrtc.CameraCapturer$1.onDone(CameraCapturer.java:47)
                                                     at org.webrtc.Camera2Session$CaptureSessionCallback.onConfigured(Camera2Session.java:233)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.InvokeDispatcher.dispatch(InvokeDispatcher.java:39)
                                                     at android.hardware.camera2.dispatch.HandlerDispatcher$1.run(HandlerDispatcher.java:65)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is my code,

```
 private VideoCapturer createCameraCapturer(CameraEnumerator enumerator) {
        final String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();
        // First, try to find front facing camera
        Logging.d(TAG, "Looking for front facing cameras.");
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                Logging.d(TAG, "Creating front facing camera capturer.");

                VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }
        // Front facing camera not found, try something else
        Logging.d(TAG, "Looking for other cameras.");
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                Logging.d(TAG, "Creating other camera capturer.");
                VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Are you calling this code on a different thread other than Main?

Answer (score 1):

try to recreate video source when number of users in session change. and add below code before creating `videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid);`

```
if(videoCapturerAndroid!=null) {
                    try {
                        videoCapturerAndroid.stopCapture();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    videoCapturerAndroid = createVideoCapturer(isFrontCamera);

                }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used, coroutine with `Dispatchers.Main`.

```kotlin
coroutine.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    webRtcClient.initLocalSurfaceView(view, isVideoCall)
}
```